# Change ComboBox item when another ComboBox item is changed in pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, combobox, pyqt, pyqt5

I have two comboboxes in my GUI. I want to change the values in the second combobox based on the selected value of the first combobox.

Like the first combobox contains values a,b,c. When **a** is selected, the second combobox will have values 1,2,3. When **b** is selected, the second combobox will have values 4,5,6 and so on.

I am trying to use if else statement with currentText() method, but it does not change.

Here is my code:

python ui:

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(832, 625)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(85, 255, 255);")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Dialog)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 190, 481, 41))
        self.comboBox.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Dialog)
        self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 290, 481, 41))
        self.comboBox_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
```

main

```
class cbox(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(cbox,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
        self.comboBox.addItems(list_1)
        list_2 = ['1','2','3']
        list_3 = ['4','5', '6']
        list_4 = ['7','8','9']
        if str(self.comboBox.currentText()) == 'a':
            self.comboBox_2.addItems(list_2)
        if str(self.comboBox.currentText()) == 'b':
            self.comboBox_2.addItems(list_3)
        if str(self.comboBox.currentText()) == 'c':
            self.comboBox_2.addItems(list_4)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mwin = cbox()
    mwin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How can I do it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the [`currentIndexChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentIndexChanged) signal, and connect to a function that updates the contents of the other combo.

```py
class cbox(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(cbox,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
        self.comboBox.addItems(list_1)
        list_2 = ['1','2','3']
        list_3 = ['4','5', '6']
        list_4 = ['7','8','9']
        self.comboBox_2.addItems(list_2)
        self.sub_lists = list_2, list_3, list_4
        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.updateCombo)

    def updateCombo(self, index):
        # first of all, clear the current contents of the combo
        self.comboBox_2.clear()
        # then, add the new items, based on the new index
        self.comboBox_2.addItems(self.sub_lists[index])
```